# csom iterate sharepoint list item and update field

Tags: splistitemcollection

I have list with 10000 record and want to update field "Business" whose value is AAA to BBB. for this I need to iterate each list items and update. Below is my code.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List name");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Business' /> <Value Type='Text'>AAA</Value> </Eq> </Where>";

        ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
            item["Business"] = "BBB";
            item.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

where I am doing wrong> in caml
Can someone help to modify to correct code

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Caml Query `ViewXml` property is missing `<View>` and `<Query>` tags

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List name");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Business' /><Value Type='Text'>AAA</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

        ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
            item["Business"] = "BBB";
            item.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Comment: yes I am using that, forget to update in code, updated now. Field update is happening. But it has updated all rows to BBB irrespective to AAA. I only want to update value of field which has value AAA

Comment: Have updated caml query view xml in the answer above. your query was missing "View" and "Query" xml tags.

Comment: Thanks  lot Vineet, it helped. just one more thing I want to add 2 parameter like if Business = AAA change to BBB and if business = XXX change to ZZZ. how to pass 2 parameter

Comment: Modify your CAML query to add an Or clause <View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Business' /><Value Type='Text'>AAA</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Business' /><Value Type='Text'>XXX</Value></Eq></Or></Where></Query></View>

Comment: item["Business"] == "AAA" ? item["Business"] = "BBB" :  item["Business"] = "ZZZ"; item.Update(); clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the camlquery to retrieve the AAA items alone and then you can modify the value without any condition,

```
Query = @"<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Business' /> <Value Type='Text'>AAA</Value> </Eq> </Where>"
```

Then modify the for loop code as below,

```
foreach (ListItem item in items) {     
item["Business"] = 'BBB';     
item.Update(); 
}
```

Please let me know, whether the above code solves your issue.

Comment: I have updated my code above(in question as per your query). It runs fine but value does not get updated

Comment: Field update is happening. But it has updated all rows to BBB irrespective to AAA. I only want to update value of field which has value AAA

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the data where business is equal to EBL, don't know its a typo mistake or not, if you change EBL to AAA in the query so I don't think so there is need of if condition. Apart from a query, I don't find any mistake in the code.